# How to download s3 bucket images from folder to local system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

How can I use regular expressions to selectively download images from an S3 bucket to my local machine? Specifically, I want to target files that start with `20231201`. Currently, I am using the S3 CLI and my commands are downloading all historical images from previous months and years. My goal is to download only the images that have filenames following this pattern:

```
https://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/20231203-6de2d5dd-7303-4841-b35c-c69e1b35d9f0.jpg
https://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/20231201-030e87e7-3a61-4748-bfa4-fbd10a2a2ecf.jpg
https://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/20231208-2220bc6b-fa21-4df9-b4d4-a47e988cab0d.jpg
https://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/20231203-a4939bde-4a14-414e-9d1a-0a89912a4f63.jpg
https://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/20231205-c2ca109d-8f7f-43ba-bd47-d6782bae0d5e.jpg
https://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/20231205-cf76fe0a-733c-4317-a0a6-a0ecd0860794.jpg
```

The command I'm currently using downloads all files from previous years:

```
aws s3 sync s3://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/ ./local-directory
```

When I attempt to download only files from `202312` using the regex pattern in the include parameter, it doesn't download anything:

```
aws s3 sync s3://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/ ./local-directory --exclude "*" --include "20231201*"
```

What should be the correct command to download all files starting with `202312`?

Comment: Did you try `--include "clients/chatbot/prod/20231201*"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command, Update the month and year based on your preference.

```bash
aws s3 sync s3://optimus-ai.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/clients/chatbot/prod/ ./local-directory --exclude "*" --include "202312*"
```